# How to build Trade Federation test cases

Tags: android, android-source, android-instrumentation, android-cts, android-tradefederation

I am able to compile and execute Trade Federation test cases which are located inside `/tools/tradefederation/core/tests`. But how can I execute the test cases which are located inside my project? My Unit and Instrumentation test cases are  located inside `/vendor/xyz/packages/apps/MyApp/test` folder. How can I build Trade Federation inside this folder and run my test cases? Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't get an answer from others, I did little research and managed to solve it myself. I built my project main classes and test classes into a separate jar file which has the reference to all its dependencies. Then I put it inside `out/host/linux-x86/tradefed` folder so that tradefed can detect my tests. Then I executed them from the terminal after building tradefed. Below Android.mk file will generate the jar file and copy it to tradefed folder,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v13 \
    android-support-v4 


LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/, res)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME:= MyUTSampleApp
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false


include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
# To include test folder.
#include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, test)
LOCAL_MODULE := sample-tests
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := mockito-host junit-host android-support-test MyUTSampleApp android_stubs_current
#LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := tradefed host-libprotobuf-java-full 


LOCAL_JAR_MANIFEST := MANIFEST.mf


include $(BUILD_HOST_JAVA_LIBRARY)


# makefile rules to copy jars to HOST_OUT/tradefed
# so tradefed.sh can automatically add to classpath
DEST_JAR := $(HOST_OUT)/tradefed/$(LOCAL_MODULE).jar
$(DEST_JAR): $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)
      $(copy-file-to-new-target)
$(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE) : $(DEST_JAR)
```

And you can use another shell script file to execute the test cases like this,

```
TEST_CLASS="com.example.myutsampleapp.LocalManagerTest"

FORWARDED_ARGS=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  next="$1"
  case ${next} in
  --class)
    TEST_CLASS="$2"
    shift
    ;;
  *)
    FORWARDED_ARGS+=("$1")
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done


/home/bsherif/workspace/source/tools/tradefederation/core/tradefed.sh run singleCommand host -n \
  --console-result-reporter:suppress-passed-tests \
  --class ${TEST_CLASS} ${FORWARDED_ARGS[*]}
```